# Discord js detect other bot's message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to detect a message that comes from another discord bot. Like for example, if the other discord bot says the word "captcha", my discord bot will detect it and ping me. Hopefully, there's also a way to detect another bot's embed too, not only messages.

Comment: Hi i guess every message has a user property containing a flag if user is a bot like message.author.bot

Answer (score 1):

You can detect if a user is a bot using the [`bot`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=bot) property on a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User).

```js
// create a message event
client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.author.bot) {
  // if the message is a bot
  console.log(`${message.author.username} sent: '${message.content}'`); // you can fetch the message text through `message.content`

  if (message.embeds[0])
   // if the message includes an embed
   console.log(
    `${message.author.username} sent an embed with the title ${message.embeds[0].title}`
   ); // you can fetch the embed content through `message.embeds[0]`
 }
});
```

Comment: works like I wanted it to be! The only problem left right now is I got the content of the embed I needed which is at the footer. I want to make a condition that if a specific word is included in the fetched embed, I'll put a react on the embed itself. Thank you for the help by the way ^^

Comment: You could try: `if (message.embeds[0].footer.includes('specific word')) message.react(reaction)`

Comment: it says`Cannot read property footer of undefined`. I tried around tweaking the code you sent me but to no avail.

Comment: That just means the particular message you called this on doesn't have an embed

Comment: Found the solution for the problem thanks to the code you sent still and asking a few around

`for (var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++) {
  if (message.embeds[i] &&
  message.embeds[i].footer &&
  message.embeds[i].footer.text.includes('left')) {
   message.react('')`
solved it and did the deed. Thank you so much for all the help ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `bot` property from `author` (user object)

`message.author.bot` will return `true` if whoever sent the message is a bot, otherwise `false`.

> For your "captcha" detection you would just need to check `message.content`